# How to White-Out/Black-Out Screen on PrintScreenButton Click?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, screenshot

How would the PrintScreenButton be prevented?

Have seen a whited-out screen for the Windows PrintScreenButton, and, in another instance, a blacked-out screen as soon as the Apple Screen-Capture function is enabled..

This is for development purposes.. To protect pre-production graphics.. Pre-Alpha, for feedback..

Comment: Why is this tagged [PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)?

Comment: This is fundamentally impossible within a browser context (and thank goodness for that). You'd have to have a fully fledged client-side application with access to the system to do anything like this.

Comment: Sure, client-side.. What code-set would recognize such system-side action?

Comment: You'd have to have an app or a custom built browser plugin for it. You'd have to build it yourself, separately for every platform out there, and for every browser brand. Then you'd have to convince your users to download and install it. It's totally insane and worth usually only for large corporations that absolutely *need* to protect their content and are ready to go through the gigantic hassle. For 99% of all cases the correct approach is to forget it, serve the content unprotected and risk some amount of misuse

Comment: Re your edit - have the people who get to see the graphics sign an NDA.  Problem solved. Given time and ability, even your print screen disabler would be trivial to circumvent - one could, for example, simply write a graphics card driver that saves every frame that is shown. Or output the graphics via HDMI and capture them on another device. This problem cannot be solved using technology

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a recommended practice, it should be possible to listen to the PrtScrn keypress and hide everything until it's released.

However, this can easily be circumvented by having another window active and pressing the key.

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 44) { //print screen button
     $('body').hide();
  }
}).on('keyup',function() {
  $('body').show();
});
```

Comment: Very cool.. Will test in the morning.. Will this work for the OS X screen-capture keypress as well? Presumably there's a different key code..? Thanks